# How to "deop" a player in the Minecraft Forge API

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I need help with opping and deop'ing a player in Minecraft Forge 1.12.2. I can find out if a player is opped, but I need to be able to first find out if the player is an OP, save that info, then deop the player. After some conditions are met, I must be able to OP a player again if he/she was OP.

Code to get OP

```
//check if payer is OP
if (plr.getServer().getPlayerList().canSendCommands(plr.getGameProfile())) {
    opped = 1;
}
else {
    opped = 0;
}
```

opped is an int.

Comment: is there no such thing as boolean?

Comment: @L_Church not as far as I know. Getting the OP/s is in the net.minecraft.entity class, But no mention was made of setting OP.It does check the player's game profile though, so it might be possible through some NBT editing. Will have a look at that

Comment: NBT is a no go. As far as I can see anyway. Maybe I should just read/write to the ops.json file.

Comment: if there isnt a dedicated thing for op setting i would just edit that directly with the users username... best of luck

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Converting OP's comment to an answer:</sub>

> Found this:
>
> ```
> MinecraftServer server = FMLCommonHandler.instance().getMinecraftServerInstance();
> server.getCommandManager(); 
> server.commandManager.executeCommand(server, rawcommand");
> ```
>
> So that means you can use it to deop and OP
>
> – [Rudi Van Eeden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4596617/rudi-van-eeden)  [Mar 6, 2018 at 19:05](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927747/minecraft-deop-a-player#comment85281477_48927747)